# How to send text to input field

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

```
driver.get("https://beta.stress.pw/login")
enter_searchbar.element = driver.find_element_by_xpath=("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/input[1]")
enter_searchbar.send_keys("itartinas1")
```

Error I get:

> Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException Message: stale
> element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax

```
enter_searchbar.element = driver.find_element_by_xpath=(<XPATH>)
```

is doing not what you expect it to do - it just added new property `element` to existed `enter_searchbar` object and set it to string `"/html/body..."`

Use correct syntax for finding element and also try to avoid using auto-generated XPath locators:

```
driver.get("https://beta.stress.pw/login")
enter_searchbar = driver.find_element_by_name("login-username")
enter_searchbar.send_keys("itartinas1")
```